# register lazyloaded controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I want to load controllers like so:

```
.state({
    name: 'app.search',
    url: 'search?q&opts',
    templateUrl: '/templates/search.html',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl',
    resolve: {
        deps: function($util){
            return $util.load(['/ctrl/SearchCtrl.js']);
        }
    }
})
```

The controller loads but i get the following error, leading me to believe that the controller was not registered:

`Argument 'SearchCtrl' is not aNaNunction, got undefined`

So my question is, how would i go about registering the controller when loading it lazily as shown.

controller is defined as:

```
app.module('app').controller('SearchCtrl',function(){

});
```

Is there anything i can do to force the controller to be registered?

**EDIT** THE APP IS ALREADY BUILT AND ALL WORKS FINE. THIS QUESTION PERTAINS TO LAZYLOADING ONLY.

The problem is exactly as defined, the controller is not registered because the bootstrapping process has already run. i'm looking for some way to register the controller when it is lazyloaded.

my loader function (`$util.load()` looks like so:

```
load: function (){

    if(arguments.length > 1){
        var items = arguments;
    }else{
        var items = arguments[0];
    }



    var _self = this;

    return $q(function(resolve,reject){
        if(items.length == 0){
            return resolve();
        }
        _self.async( items, function(item,next){
            if(item.indexOf('.js') != -1){
                _self.loadOne('script',item,next,function(err){
                    next(err);
                }); 
            }
            else if(item.indexOf('.css') != -1){
                _self.loadOne('link',item,next);
            }else{

                next();
            }
        },function(errors,results){
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.$apply();// @Claies suggestion
                if(errors){
                    reject(errors);
                }else{
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });

},
```

Comment: do you have a module declared separately?

Comment: the app module? of course. this app is already built, but all of the code is in a single file. i'm trying to split all the code into seperate files and lazyload

Comment: you'll need to use `$rootScope.$apply()` *after* your loader loads and executes your controller file but *before* the resolve is returned.  you could also use a module designed for this task, like oc-lazyLoad.  https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router

Comment: @Claies thanks, i'll give it a go.

Comment: @Claies that didn't work.

Comment: @Claies yeah, lets bring in a 60kb library to lazyload 14kb of code. i don't understand why this has to be so difficult in angular.js

Comment: You probably need to 'proxy' your controller, so you can register the proxy at the beginning, without loading the controller code and the load the controller when you need. This slideshare contains some useful hints https://www.slideshare.net/nirkaufman/angularjs-lazy-loading-techniques. It's just a trace of work as they use require.js (also oclazyload, but for your needs only require would be enough), instead you want to do it manually. But it gives good hints. I don't know if I have the time to write an answer, I hope so, today

Comment: @Massimo see my previous reply. RequireJS is not going to cut it. Same problem as ocLazyLoad, bringing in an extra library to handle something that should be easy to do in few loc.

Comment: I know, in fact I think you've to implement your proxy manually

Comment: i guess by proxy you mean overriding angular.module, then appInstance.controller and proxying calls from this overriden function to $controllerProvider? thanks. post your comment as an answer, will gladly give you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself by overriding `angular.module()` with a custom function, and within this custom function i pass calls to appInstance.controller to $controllerProvider.register(). it is working, i'm not sure how proper it is but i don't really care as long as it doesn't break anything.

```
var mod = angular.module('myModule',[]); //define my module

mod.config(['$controllerProvider',function($controllerProvider){

    mod._cRegister = $controllerProvider;//store controllerProvider onto the app instance.

    var mFunc = angular.module; // copy actual module function from angular

    //override angular.module with custom function
    angular.module = function(){

        var app = mFunc.apply(this,arguments);// proxy to the real angular.module function to get an app instance

        var cFunc = app.controller;//copy actual controller function from app instance

        app.controller = function(){

            mod._cRegister.register.apply(this,arguments); // try register on the controllerProvider instance as well


            return this;//return app instance so user can chain calls or whatever.

        }.bind(app);

        return app;//return app instance, just as angular does.

    }.bind(angular);    

}]);

//rest of module code (including the loader)
```

This works great, but only for controllers. following is a full example covering controllers, directives, components, factories, services, values, constants, and filters:

```
var mod = angular.module('myModule',[]);

mod.config(['$controllerProvider','$compileProvider','$filterProvider','$provide',function($controllerProvider,$compileProvider,$filterProvider,$provide){

    mod.$controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
    mod.$compileProvider = $compileProvider;
    mod.$filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    mod.$provide = $provide;

    var map = {
        controller: ['$controllerProvider','register'],
        filter: ['$filterProvider','register'],
        service: ['$provide','service'],
        factory: ['$provide','factory'],
        value: ['$provide','value'],
        constant: ['$provide','constant'],
        directive: ['$compileProvider','directive'],
        component: ['$compileProvider','component']
    };

    var bootStrapped = [];

    var mFunc = angular.module;

    angular.module = function(){

        var app = mFunc.apply(this,arguments);

        //only override properties once.
        if(bootStrapped.indexOf(arguments[0]) == -1){
            for(var type in map){

                var c = mod;

                var d = map[type];

                for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
                    c = c[d[i]];// recurse until reaching the function
                }
                //now inject the function into an IIFE so we ensure its scoped properly
                !function(app,type,c){
                    app[type] = function(){
                        c.apply(this,arguments);
                        return this;//return the app instance for chaining.
                    }.bind(app);    
                }(app,type,c);
            }   
            bootStrapped.push(arguments[0]);//mark this instance as properly monkey patched
        }

        return app;

    }.bind(angular);    

}]);
```

Comment: @Disfigure if you need a tiny library for lazyloading i've got one up on github/bower checkout `ng-util` package. its not just lazyloading either, it does all types of shit, like synchronous and asynchronous iterators(function queues) with guaranteed return orders, and some random directives and filters. all in about 2.8kb

Comment: Nice to hear that, i've been looking for something like that since a while. If you have any other useful package do not hesitate haha